# Access cannot find the referenced form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am in the final stages of testing a small piece of software I made, and am experiencing a `Access cannot find the referenced form 'Customer Picker'`:

[image]

I've checked over my syntax for accessing the form, and there's nothing wrong with it. 
I've also looked for a solution to this (this issue being [well documented on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903606/cannot-find-the-referenced-form)) but nothing has worked.

This is the (partial) code I'm using:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoice", acViewPreview
If (Forms![Customer Picker]![Combo3].Value = "Business") Then
    Reports![Invoice]![Text154] = Forms![Customer Picker]![Text8]
Else
    Reports![Invoice]![Text154] = Forms![Customer Picker]![Text10] + " " + Forms![Customer Picker]![Text6]
End If
```

My objective is to populate a report based on the information entered in the form, and then print the report (haven't got as far as that yet).

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only reference `Forms![Customer Picker]` when the form is open. 
But you reported that `CurrentProject.AllForms("Customer Picker").IsLoaded` returned False.

If it is included as a subform in some other form which is open, you can reference it via the name of the subform *control* on that other form:

```vb
Forms![Other Form]![Subform Control]![Text8]
```

Note that the name of the subform control may not be the same as the name of the form which it contains.